# How to make image on the full width of parent block?

Tags: html, css

I have `div` block with `img` inside. I tried to make img on the full width of parent:

```
<div><img></div>
```

**CSS**

```
img {
  display: block;
  margin:0px
  position: relative
}

div {
  overflow: hidden
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Block element takes full width of parent container, just your container doesn't have width.. and you must specify max-width of image because it will overflow container if it's larger

Like this :

```css
div{
  width:200px; 
}
img{
  max-width:100%;
  
}
```

```html
<div>
   <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/24/Male_mallard_duck_2.jpg"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    position: relative; // fix for old IE browsers and some blackberry browsers like UC Browser.
    box-sizing: border-box; // fix for old operamini browsers and Get as Google preview
}
```